# Parse double comma separated unichar from xml and display it in regular arabic letters

Tags: objective-c

I want to know how can i parse data like: `charcode="0x0644,0x0625"` double comma separated unichar from xml file and convert them to regular arabic letter. The unichar above is two regular arabic letters that must be appended. But I wonder how to parse it because i am new in objective-c and don't know how.

this is how I have parsed single unichar from xml file:

```
-(void)loadDataFromXML{

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"alphabet" ofType: @"xml"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];
    NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    [parser release];

}
```

And:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"letter"]) {
        name = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"name"];   
        charcode  =[attributeDict valueForKey:@"charcode"];
        namesound =[attributeDict valueForKey:@"namesound"];
        status=@"0";

        uint charValue;
       [[NSScanner scannerWithString:charcode] scanHexInt:&charValue];
       charcode=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", charValue];

  }
}
```

**thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Amir, check if your string contain a comma. If yes, then explode your string by this comma char

```
 NSString *testString= @"0x0644,0x0625";
 NSArray *array = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

After that give a for loop for each of your array; convert each element to a string, make some convert operations with every charcode and concatinate result strings

Comment: Thanks, I have solved the problem by creating a string scanner using ([charcode rangeOfString:@","].location == NSNotFound). Using this i will synchronize the parsed unichars by converting them with %C and %C%C and add appended letters into the database.